# Financial Time series prediction/ SV Regression

Tags: artificial-intelligence, regression, svm, prediction

I'm working with R software (Lib e1071) and I'm trying to get predictions using Support Vector Regression. The way I'm doing it is the following:

I'm windowizing the raw closing prices using N=3 yields:

```
s[t-3]    s[t-2]     s[t-1]   ->   s[t]
1.2350    1.2358     1.2354        1.2360
.         .          .             .
.         .          .             .

etc...
```

The value I want to predict is *y=s[t]*. The SVM Type is "eps-regression" and the Kernel is "radial". Also, I perform a 10-fold cross validation to get the best parameters, gamma and cost.

But I have a problem:

The prediction is always a very close value of the last value *s[k-1]*, for instance:

```
Last Vector: 

s[t-3]    s[t-2]     s[t-1]   ->   s[t]

1.2350    1.2358     1.2354        1.2355
```

The predicted values are going to be very close values of the last s[t-1] value. I have tried increasing the number of learned vectors (10K) and increasing the N yields (up to 7), but the results are the same.

Can anybody tell me why is this happening and how could I get real predictions?

**

## Addendum

**

Regarding the kind reply from user__42, I have some issues understanding your explanation:

1) Lets say I have the following 3 trained vector set

```
10 s[t-3]          12 s[t-2]        15 s[t-1]    ->      11 s[t]  
5  s[t-4]          8  s[t-3]        9  s[t-2]    ->      10 s[t-1]
6  s[t-5]          12 s[t-4]        10 s[t-3]    ->      15 s[t-2]
```

The attempted prediction suggested is *y'*:

```
y'[t] = y[t] - y[-t]
```

Taking the above example

```
y'[t] = 11 - 15  -> y'[t] = y[t] - y[-1]
```

But in real time prediction, I don't know *y[t]* to calculate *y'*:

```
y'[t] = x - 15
```

2) Considering the above example, could you please explain what do you mean by the following expressions:

```
y'[nt] 


y'[-nt] 


y[nt]
```

Comment: This maybe better for http://stats.stackexchange.com/.  They may have more insight.

Comment: What do you want to do? Financial data is a too broad term.

Comment: I hope it's more clear now. Thanks.

Comment: Probably still better for [stats.stackexchange.com](http://stats.stackexchange.com/), but it's now actionable...

Answer (score 0):

If you use real financial time series data **this behaviour is part of the challenge** - since financial time series are **very noisy**.

You could try:

1. write down your kernel-parameters and try nu-SVR with the same kernel-parameters and select nu=0.1. This way you will increase model complexity converging against "rote learning"(translated with google! "auswendiglernen" in german)

1.a.edit You can try a loss function which is not the Classic ε-insensitive LF, like the Gaussian loss funktion ( no xp myself)

1.b.edit I did use FaLK-SVR once. There u can split the data in sub-data-neighbourhoods: **I think this will help you to get less "averaged" results.** FaLKM-lib is a ready to use implementation basing on libSVM: http://disi.unitn.it/~segata/FaLKM-lib/

1. include s[t-13] and s[t-27] (not the values in between! only (t-1,t-2,t-3,t-13 and t-27) to give the machine a clue about the general trend.
2. you certainly need more features if you seriously try to predict series like this say the weather ;-), [micro-blogging](http://www.cs.ucr.edu/~vagelis/publications/wsdm2012-microblog-financial.pdf) or computed features (via hidden markov)
3. Google for easier toy-data or look [here](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvmtools/datasets/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did try your suggestions (1. and 2.) and unfortunately, I'm getting the same behavior. Predictions always are very close to the last price. Maybe increasing the spacing of the time series may help? i.e: (t-2,t-5,t-9,t-13 and t-27)

Comment: Update: I increased the spacing like this: [t-1],[t-13],[t-27] including the suggestions 1. and 2. Result: the same initial outcome.

Comment: Ok let me clearify no3: Your Input values are simple y[-t] values - so the machines is not wrong taking y[-1] as closest guess on y. Try predicting the y'[t]=y[t]-y[-t] use y'[-nt] as Input also. This way your Kernel Distance from x1=[1,2,3,4] to x2=[3,4,5,6] will be zero. If you need y[t] as output simply add (known) y[-t] to y'[t]. Also try mixed y'[-nt] and y[-nt] values to cover different behavior on low and high values. Try to put as much information as you can imagine of into the kernel. Play with (y[-nt]-y[-nt-2]) and so on...

Comment: Thank you for your insight. Could you please refer to the addendum above at the initial question to clarify some points? Thanks again.

Comment: please replace "-nt" with "t-n" in the comment above. With x1 and x2 i was refering to your original input. If you take the differential of those values: x1*=[1,1,1,1] and x2*=[1,1,1,1] the kernel distance between x1* and x2* with any kernel is 0. Ok. Now to keep things easy we want to predict y1 = 5 and y2 = 7. So y1* = y1' = 1 and y2* = y2' = 1 also. If we have a machine predicting y1* and y2* we need to add y' to (known) y[t-1] to get back to the desired y. here: y1 = y1* + y1[t-1] = 1 + 4 = 5 and y2 = y2* + y2[t-1] = 1 + 6 = 7. So you predict y' and calculate y from it.

Comment: please excuse my wrong math - i'm an engineer... you can look here for discrete derivatives: math.stackexchange.com/questions/302160/… . Note that there are several ways to compute discrete

Comment: I have built the following model: Type:nu-regression, Kernel:radial, cost:10, gamma:1e-06, nu:0.1. Input values are the difference between the current price bar and the last price bar(discrete derivatives) i.e:[2,1,5,3,9], N=5 yields. The result is almost invariable of this kind: 0.1475, 0.1395, 0.1245, etc. In other words, the predicted variable never moves more than 1 point. It seems the problem persists.

Comment: Thank you for your edits. 1a. Can you suggest how can I implement the Gaussian loss function with R? 1b. Unfortunately, FaLK-SVR does not work with R as far as I see. Is there any possibility to work with subdata neighborhoods within R? I'd love to establish a chat session but my reputation still does not permit it. Thanks.